# Java applet cannot be run

Tags: java, applet, awt, appletviewer

I am trying to run a java applet with instruction on the textbook.
The code is as below.But when I run the appletviewer in cmd the appletviewer is not running.
The CMD command is as below

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;

public class HelloAgainApplet extends java.applet.Applet{

    Font f = new Font ("TimesRoman" ,Font.BOLD,36);

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setFont(f);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("HelloAgain!", 5, 50);
    }
}
```

---

```
C:\HTML>appletviewer -debug HelloAgainApplet.class Initializing jdb
 ...
 > run run sun.applet.Main HelloAgainApplet.class VM start exception: VM initialization failed for: C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\bin\java -Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre\phony -Xdebug
 -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,address=javadebug66917,suspend=y sun.applet.Main HelloAgainApplet.class

 Error: Could not find or load main class Files

 Fatal error: Target VM failed to initialize.
```

May I know why the error occurs? Is it that I had not set the classpath for the java appletviewer?

Comment: You need to pass it the html page *"appletviewer <options> url(s)*"

Comment: But I just want the appletviewer to show applet without the html page.

Comment: But that's not how the appletviewer works, it uses the html to find and load the applet classes

Comment: Look at the example code in the [applet info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info),  It includes the HTML in the source code.  Then it can be run using something like `appletviewer HelloWorld.java`  (note it is **`.java`** not **`.class`**).

Comment: Thanks You @MadProgrammer. As you say I run the applet in HTML Pages.Now my applet viewer can be running.But I can't run that file in my firefox.Is there any issues.I had enable the security signning in the java control panel with local address of the file

<code>
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
//import java.applet.*;

public class HelloAgainApplet extends java.applet.Applet {

 Font f = new Font ("TimesRoman" ,Font.BOLD,36);
 
 public void paint(Graphics g){
  g.setFont(f);
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.drawString("HelloAgain!", 5, 50);
  
 }
 
}
</code>

Comment: It's been years (literally 10+) since I had to deal with applets at any serious level. I believe that now, your applet MUST be signed before any browser will even look at it, which in my opinion, makes it a dead technology, with many other, better solutions available.  Have a look at [Java Applets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Thanks You. Many thanks to your helping hand.I learn a lot now.And also Andrew Thompson.Thanks You.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with a java version higher than 1.8 as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505959/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-sun-applet-appletviewer and others.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an html file that references your class file as argument to appletviewer:

###### Sample "Applet.html"

```
<applet code="HelloAgainApplet" width=200 height=60></applet>
```

Then start via

```
appletviewer -debug Applet.html
```

and run the applet with a simple `run` command. The CLI should look like this:

```
appletviewer.exe -debug Applet.html
Initializing jdb ...
> run
run sun.applet.Main Applet.html
...
```