# Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse and I'm creating this `java applet` but I keep getting below error when I tried to run an applet. I know it's deprecated in the new version (I even tired 1.8) but is there something I can use to make it work?

> Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.applet.AppletViewer

[image]

Comment: Java applets are **dead**.

Comment: Im kinda new to java and my professor was importing java applet and it was working for him.

Comment: You are running Java 11, this does not have AppletViewer. You will have to run with an older Java.

Comment: So I don't need to downgrade my eclipse version, but Java? Yes?

Comment: Yes you would have to use an older java version. Preferably Java 8 (not too old for IDEs and not too young to deny access to internal/private packages like sun.applet.AppletViewer).

Comment: That works! Im now using 8. Thanks guys!

Comment: The real solution is to stop using applets.  Java 8 is due to be EOL'd in December 2020.  Someone needs to tell your professor to update his courses.  He shouldn't be teaching applets anymore.

Comment: @tobain - the `AppletViewer` class no longer exists in Java 11.  It is gone.   And Java 9 / 10 are already EOL'd.

Comment: @StephenC The issue is, Java textbooks don't really get outdated quickly, and can easily be used for a very long time, so if possible, schools will do so. Many of these older textbooks contain projects that involve using applets. Even if the school has students buying new textbooks, they may use an old curriculum too, as it's already been tried and tested. So applets tend to be used anyways, even though they're dead, simply because it's another thing to assign, and more for the students to work on and learn from.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't wash.  You (the student) are paying good money for your education.  If you are being taught stuff that is out of date, then you should be asking for your money back.  Because the stuff that you learn about applets won't be any help to you in getting a job.  Your teacher should be teaching you to build Android apps or JavaFX.  Your school needs to invest in updating its curriculum.

Comment: Besides, where I come from, students buy their own textbooks.

Answer (score 12):

I think you are using *jdk-13*. However, Applets support *jdk-8* and lower.

The current solution for you would be:

1. Install *jdk-8* and open Eclipse.
2. Go to *Window -> Preferences -> Add -> next* and find your jvm folder(e.g. */usr/lib/jvm*).
3. From there select *jdk-8*.
4. After adding jdk-8, remove the jdk-13 from *Preferences*.

After everything here, it should start working. If you encounter the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Assistive Technology not found: org.GNOME.Accessibility.AtkWrapper

you can simply run this command

`sudo sed -i -e '/^assistive_technologies=/s/^/#/' /etc/java-*-openjdk/accessibility.properties`

Answer (score 1):

For support of Applets in Netbeans, you can edit the path to your JDK in netbeans config file which is found in /netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf. Change the line netbeans_jdkhome="" to your JDK 8 e.g netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_241-amd64/"