# How to fix error message about being unable to find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer?

Tags: java, applet

[Image of what my screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umFoq.jpg)

This is what my program looks like at the very top:

```
// imports all needed libraries
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScreenSaverProject extends GraphicsProgram {

    // sets up canvas and canvas size
    public void init() {
        resize(1200, 700);
    }
    
    // holds all the code that the program will run
    public void run() {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505959/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-sun-applet-appletviewer)

Answer (score 1):

Applets support jdk-8 and lower but you are using jdk 14.

See this answer:

[Error: Could not find or load main class sun.applet.AppletViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505959/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-sun-applet-appletviewer)

Comment: I can't download it: “JDK 8 Update 251.pkg” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: As everyone is saying, you should stop learning about applets and research first about what technologies you should be learning.